# Ignore first x lines when executing a script?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, exec

I'm making a script that eventually starts over by executing itself again using `exec`. The problem is the first few lines are only supposed to be run everytime you launch the script yourself, so I'm wondering if there's any thing I can do to fix this. Here's an example:

```
echo "welcome"
read yesno

if [[ $something = etc.. ]]; then
whatever
fi

exec ~/bin/script
```

This is simplified but it this were my script I would want to ignore the first line, (`echo`). Is there some option to `exec` I can add? I mean I could make a copy of the script and just omit the first line(s), but it feels like a bad solution.

Comment: Why not add a parameter to the script?  (Alternatively, set an environment variable which the script can test).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a variable, the obvious thing to do is to pass in the result from the previous prompt:

```
if [[ -z "$yesno" ]]; then
    echo "welcome"
    read yesno
fi

if [[ $something = etc.. ]]; then
whatever
fi

# doing it this way makes it exported into the subprocess
yesno=$yesno exec ~/bin/script
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple like that. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try placing a temp file in /run, check at start if it exists. If not, you can echo, if it exists, you've run it before. And when you finish remove that file.